# Scheduling access to SSH on Azure

Tags: ssh, azure

I have the need to automatically dump a MySQL database on one server with mysqldump, copy it to another server (probably using rsync), and then import it on the server it was copied to with mysql.

Due to some attacks on the platform in question, as well as it being good practice, SSH is closed unless required to be open for maintenance or code deploys.

**How can I automate opening of SSH on Azure to allow my scripts and commands to run and close after?** Or is there a way to do the above without SSH?

Comment: You could try port knocking.  Here's a pretty good description from a quick google: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/implement_port_knocking_using_iptables.html  Be sure to read up on the subject fully to see if it's a good fit for your security requirements.

Comment: @BrandonXavier, thank you for that. From what I can see, that will address an issue that can assist with ensuring "who" wants access, but it does not address the "how" of simply telling Azure to "open SSH now as if I had to click button X that opens it". Does that make sense what I am asking?

Comment: I'll admit I have no direct experience with Azure - but if allowing access via iptables is all that is needed (and not something else from something such an Azure control panel), this really should do the trick - the last step in the chain is, after receiving the 3 correct knocks, to enable traffic on the desired port (22 in your case) at the VM level.

Comment: After re-reading my last comment, this may not be such a good solution after all.  The problem being you would have to allow at least the 3 knock ports thru to the VM - which is going to possibly (seriously) lessen the effective security of such a solution.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for your comments. I will wait and see what others advise, if any :-)

Comment: Have you considered securing ssh (and the system generally) instead?

Comment: I can only access SSH with an SSH key. That is not the issue, if I understand you correctly. The issue is that I want to open SSH at run time to run my scripts, then close it at run time again, within the Azure environment. We have DDoS mitigation, SSH is blocked unless needed. But this also falls out of my purview. I just need to come up with a proposal to the IT infrastructure team with the use case to allow run time opening/closing of SSH. I want to know how and if this can be done in Azure before approaching them. Due diligence, and all.

Comment: Do you need to open SSH access at a specific time, or does it need to be triggered by something else?

Comment: Need to open it at a specific time, and close again at a specific time. But at "run time" for lack of a better term; no human intervention to do the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your needing to do this at a fixed time then I would recommend using either Azure Automation or an Azure Function on a timer trigger. You can schedule this to run at a specific time and call into Azure using the Azure PowerShell Cmdlets or REST API to open up the network security group at a specific time, and close it again later.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I spoke to the infrastructure team, and they seem confident that this would work. Thanks for your answer.